# How to Test a Trigger -- Test Passes But Doesn't Cover Code?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, code

I've created a simple trigger that posts a user's field entries to chatter whenever they create or update a new record on the Weather Tracker custom object. It works. The problem I have is writing test code. My test code doesn't fail, but when I view my trigger's code coverage, it says 0%. What am I missing??

[image: Trigger]

[image: Trigger-Test]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never inserting your weather_tracker__c record. Add this statement to your test method

```
insert wt;
```

after you set the air_temp__c field.

Comment: Also, make sure you are running your test classes in async method. If you goto developer console and Test -> Always Run Asynchronously should be checked.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that part out after reading through other examples. But now,  just before that insert, I have a required field that's part of the master-detail relationship. It's the name field. The selection would be 'JAN-9', for example. How do I populate this field with a selection from a related object?

Comment: If weather_tracker__c is the detail int he master-detail relationship, you'll need to create a parent object, insert it, and then associate the records. Populate the master-detail field on the child, with the Id of the parent.

Comment: I just went ahead and eliminated the relationship. I wasn't absolutely sure that it was needed anyway. This moved my code coverage to 100%. Thanks for the help bro. I checked your response as the answer :)